# What is the best way to ensure that a property is present during initialization?

Tags: objective-c, initialization

I have created a class, `Metrics` that is designed to be subclassed to customize behavior. In order to make this more robust, the init method of `Metrics` calls a method named `setup` that does nothing by default. If subclasses want to customize behavior during initialization (which they commonly do) they can override this method. Since the default implementation does nothing, there's no need to remember to call `[super setup]`.

I like the way that this works so far, it's robust and easy to use. The problem I have now is that there are times when the setup method requires some additional property to be set. An example:

```
@implimentation Metrics

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    // Do all the required initialization
  }
}

@end

@interface SubclassOfMetrics : Metrics {}

@property (assign) CGFloat width;

@end

@implimentation SubclassOfMetrics

- (void)setup {
  // This method is indirectly called as a result of the superclass initialization
  // The code here depends on the `width` property being set
}

@end
```

The problem I have is that setup is called before the property `width` can be set. What options do I have here? I can work around this by not initializing my `Metrics` class in the init method. I can do it explicitly after I have set the properties I need to set. I'm not of fan of this, as it requires me to perform actions in a certain order and remember to setup. Do I have any other options?

Edit: The root of problem is really that the initialization of the `Metrics` class does a lot of calculations. The results of those calculations will depend on the properties being set in a subclass, so I need a way to get those properties set *before* the superclass is done initializing.

Comment: +1... Interesting question.  I'm sure there's a reason, but what's the purpose of setup in this case?  Couldn't the subclasses implement their initialization behavior in their own init methods instead of the setup method?

Comment: Overriding the initializer is possible, but more difficult because of the way the class is instantiated. The class that does the init'ing doesn't know about `SubclassOfMetrics`, so it wouldn't know to call the special init method. It's class-clustery.

Comment: Also, having the `setup` method makes subclassing really easy, and this class is designed to be subclassed, so I want to make it as painless and robust as possible.

Comment: Also, the setup method isn't called directly from the init method (like it is in my example), it's called about 5 frames down on the stack after the code has wound through a few other classes in addition to `Metrics`.

Comment: @kubi if the class instantiating SubclassOfMetrics does not know anything about it why would the new properties for that subclass matter. It sounds like with your setup you would be assigning defaults.You may want to look at how to implement a [class cluster](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ClassClusters) for your "class-clustery".

Comment: @kubi if your setup method isn't being called in the same way as your example, you should probably show where/how it's being called; as your current example stands, there's simply no reason for setup to exist.

Comment: also, unfortunately I can't think of a way in which this wouldn't force grandchildren of Metrics to call [super setup] if they want to use and expand upon the functionality within subclassOfMetrics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the iVars before initializing the superclass.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andMetricWidth:(CGFloat)inWidth {
  _width = inWidth

  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
  }

  return self;
}
```

I intentionally set the iVar directly to avoid any potential side-effects from using the property syntax. I haven't fully thought through how this would work with objects under ARC, but it works just fine with primitives.

Answer (score 2):

The initializers for objects are already designed to be this "setup" you are trying to create. You should just use the initializer and do any setup necessary specific to the class after you call the super initializer. When you have new properties that need to be taken into account for initialization (setup) create a new designated initializer for your sub class. This dependency injection will improve your overall design and satisfy your initialization needs.

```
@implementation Metrics

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    //Just setup here, or call a method if you prefer
  }
}

@end

@interface SubclassOfMetrics : Metrics {}

@property (assign) CGFloat width;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andMetricWidth:(CGFloat)inWidth;

@end

@implementation SubclassOfMetrics

@synthesize width;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andMetricWidth:(CGFloat)inWidth {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    self.width = inWidth;
    //do your setup here and use the width
  }
}

@end
```

Comment: I updated my question. Part of the problem, probably the root of the entire problem, is that the initialization of the superclass depends on the properties of the subclass, so I need to ensure that those properties are set before the initialization occurs.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to explicitly tell the `Metrics` class to set itself up when you are finished setting the properties… but that smells funny to me and I'm looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If your `Metrics` object is an instance variable of another object, such as a controller or any other class, you can use that class to send messages to `Metrics` once information has been determined that is necessary for the object's setup. I will often do something like this:

`Metrics*myMetrics=[[Metrics alloc] init]; // just creates the Metrics object`

I might do this in the controller's `viewDidLoad` or wherever is appropriate.

Then later, you can do this from your controlling object:

`[self.myMetrics setup];`

If it requires something like "width" you can either set a `Metrics` ivar and call it from within `setup` or send the width or whatever else you need as an argument to the `setup` method. Many different ways to go about it here. (or if `width` is a property of `Metrics` already, like a `frame` property, then you wouldn't need to pass it. Just call `setup` after you have set the `Metrics` frame size, if applicable.)

Comment: This will work, but I don't like the idea of having to call a setup method. If you forget, you've got a whole lot of uninitialized object.

Comment: true, it just depends on your overall architecture and style. i personally use this method a lot, but i also use the notification center religiously in my dynamic manipulations of views and objects, so a lot is handled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem. `Setup` should generally not rely on the behaviour of a subclass. If setup depends on `self.width`, override the `width` getter in the subclass. That should give you the `width` of the subclass.

Take a look at the following simple setup. The method `- (CGFloat) width` overrides the synthesized getter in `Metrics` and nicely returns `17.33`.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Metrics : NSObject 
- (id) init;
- (void) setup;
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat width;
@end

@interface SubclassOfMetrics : Metrics
- (CGFloat) width;
@end

@implementation Metrics
@synthesize width;
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
        [self setup];

    return self;
}
- (void) setup;
{
    NSLog(@"%f", self.width);
}
@end

@implementation SubclassOfMetrics
- (CGFloat) width
{
    return 17.33;
}
@end


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Metrics *met = [[SubclassOfMetrics alloc] init];
    [met release];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

The output is, as expected:

```
2011-08-31 18:09:41.630 MetricsTest[44098:707] 17.330000
```

This assumes that `width` is known (e.g. passed as parameter to an `initXYZ:` method of `SubclassOfMetrics`) at the time `setup` is called. Otherwise you'll have to call `setup` manually, as soon as the actual `width` is set.

Comment: My example was a necessary simplification. A more verbose description would be that `Metrics` setups up a view, sets itself as the delegate, `SubclassOfMetrics` implements the delegate method. `Metrics` isn't directly calling the subclass method. Except our situation is more convoluted then that.

Comment: But it can "virtually call" the subclass method. What is deciding is when width is know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if there's a particular reason the functionality in `-setup` can't simply be refactored into `-initWithFrame:`, so I'm going to disclaim this answer with a request to see a more accurate version of your methods, so we can see when `-setup` is being called.

The fact of the matter is that at some point, somewhere, you have to remember to "perform actions in a certain order" if you want a properly initialized object--especially when it involves class hierarchies. The way your current example works, all subclasses of Metrics, as well as their subclasses, are calling the same mostly useless init method. This may make it easy to drop in a first-generation subclass and automatically call its version of `-setup`, because it's overriding its parent's no-op method, if you someday decide that its worthwhile to sublcass `subclassOfMetrics`, you're going to wind up replacing a functional version of `-setup`, or having to remember to call `[super setup]` to get the functionality, defeating the purpose of your hack anyway.

This is of course assuming that you didn't have to worry about adding new ivars, which you of course do.

The fact of the matter is that the `-init` function is specifically meant to initialize a class's ivars, and the common convention is setup so that you only have one function in each class in which you have to remember to "perform actions in a certain order". A well-written series of init functions allows you to not have to worry when to call a method like `-setup` 5 frames deeper into function stack. The current convention of "call super's init, initialize my ivars, do extraneous setup" exists because it ensures that all setup for a class is done in the correct order, no matter how many generations deep your hierarchy ends up being.

The code is boilerplate (while still staying pretty minimal), with the **only real decisions you need to make being "should this piece of necessary setup go in `init`, where it will affect all children, or should it go in a `-setup` function, which will only be called once, and will be very specific to my class?"**
(bolded for importance)

Then, once you have a good init, you can make a simple class method that looks like this:

```
+ (Metric*) newMetricWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    Metrics* theMetric = [[self alloc] init]; //this will allow you to call it on whatever class you want and get the correct, fully initialized object
    [theMetric setup]; //this will call the correct setup method
    return theMetric;
}
```

You can then call that function like this `[subclassOfMetrics newMetricWithFrame:frame];` and you'll get back an object which the compiler will treat as a `Metric`, but which will respond to all method calls as a `subclassOfMetrics`. You can also cast the return result so that the compiler won't complain about calling subclass-specific methods on it:

`subclassOfMetrics* theSub = (subclassOfMetrics*) [subclassOfMetrics newMetricWithFrame:frame];
[theSub subclassSpecificMethod];`

Answer (score 0):

You can have your controller call the methods in your `Metrics` subclass(es) before it then calls the `setup` - or, if you don't like that approach, use the `notification center` and register `Metrics` to be notified when the calculations are done in your subclasses, and then in your subclasses post a notification when they complete the calculations. It's quite easy and very convenient way to do this sort of thing. When `Metrics` receives this notification, it then runs the `setup` method. If `Metrics` is a view or something which you want to be fully setup before showing to the screen, add another `notification` that the view controller receives when `Metrics` is done with `setup` and then have the controller `addSubview` *after* all that is complete.

Comment: The notification center solution doesn't help. I still have to post the notification. Why not just call up to the superclass?

Comment: that's really bad program design to call the superclass. what's wrong with posting a notification? the notification center was designed for things like this (and more). If A depends on B but B depends on A, why not use the very easy notification center to pass messages around so objects know when to do something, based on other parameters?

Comment: It's the exact same issue. The subclass is required to post a notification or it's required to call a superclass method. Either way, you still have some level of dependency between the two.

Comment: nsnotification center is a vastly superior and safer way to send information to a superclass than actually calling the superclass directly

Comment: How so? It's more complex to call, it requires changes to the superclass, it's asynchronous (which in this case I don't need or want). I see only downsides, no upsides. And, FWIW, calling back to the superclass is *very* common in Apple's own classes. See `[self setNeedsDisplay];`